# What is the __proto__ value of an object that is being created by constructor

Tags: javascript, prototype

I know that it seems that there is a lot of reference in the net or books for my question, but believe me that if i'm asking it's mean that after reading books/seeing videos i'm very confused. So please try to help without judging :)
I have the following code:

```
  const Person = function (firstName, birthYear) {
  // Instance properties
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.birthYear = birthYear;
```

I'm creating an object of Person:

```
let p = new Person('Mike',35)
```

Then when printing **p** to console is see that the ****proto**** property is from Object type and not a Person type. Am i reading it wrong or i don't understand the prototype theory?

[image]

My miss confuse maybe from a lecture i saw:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

__proto__ points to Person.prototype in this case

Edit: Ahhh, I finally see what you're asking, you were thinking in another Programing language where there's "type". You see in JS, function is an Object. There's no class. Every Object you created will be type "Object".

Comment: Can you expand on what this means and how I would use `Person.prototype`?

Comment: @ravenchaser,  so why does  the screenshot display `object`? BTW i'm not the one who voted your answer down since i don't really know the correct answer

Comment: ok, so how I understanded was that \_\_proto\_\_ the "getter" of prototype object. So whenever the object is created, in this case Person, prototype is also created, which inherited all the property from the Object. Perhaps someone can explain this little better, or some googling might help

Comment: forgot to mention that, \_\_proto\_\_ is deprecated last time I check. So moving forward, if you want to add a method or property to an Object, just use Person.prototype.