# Is it possible to have inner property while outer property is empty?

Tags: javascript, console

I have the following code:

```
      const Person = function (firstName, birthYear) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.birthYear = birthYear;
};

Person.prototype.calcAge = function () {
  console.log(2037 - this.birthYear);
};

const Student = function (firstName, birthYear, course) {
  Person.call(this, firstName, birthYear);
  this.course = course;
};

// Linking prototypes
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

when i'm printing to console :

> Student.prototype

I'm getting an empty object {}
When i'm printing to console:

> Student.prototype.**proto**

shouldn't i get **undefined**  here??

Attached Screenshot
[image]

Comment: I don't see what `.property` and `.typo` have to do with the above code? Also notice that `Student != Student.prototype`.

Comment: @Bergi, this is the code i have written when encounter this issue. Isn't it possible to refer to the situation?

Comment: No, in that code `Student.property` is not an empty object, and accessing `Student.property.typo` throws an *`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'typo' of undefined`* not something about "*not an empty object*". Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] please?

Comment: @Bergi, i have added a screenshot exactly with the code i wrote in my post.. the screenshot includes the outputs.. I don't see any exception

Comment: That's `Student.prototype`, not `Student.property`

Comment: "*How is it possible that an empty object can have a property*" - it doesn't have an *own* property. It **inherits** that property from its prototype - welcome to OOP :-)

Comment: @Bergi, but he has the `prototype` property.. So why it is being inherited? can you please describe who inherit from who?

Comment: The `Student` function object has a `.prototype` property, yes. That `Student.prototype` object has no properties, but it does inherit (e.g. `calcAge`) from `Person.prototype` (since that's how you `Object.create`d it).

Comment: See also the diagram in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65534445/what-is-the-proto-value-of-an-object-that-is-being-created-by-constructor

Comment: If you meant `__proto__` not `__typo__`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/1048572

Comment: @Bergi, can't understand no matter what i do... The only solution is to leave this language :( i'm broken.. and yes i meant to __proto__

Comment: You might want to ask your lecturer then. StackOverflow is the wrong platform for a tutorial on prototypical inheritance.

Comment: I have fixed my post.. really had there terrible mistakes.. the only thing i can't understand it is how an empty object Student.prototype can have a value for Student.prototype.__proto__, shouldn't it be equal to undefined`?

Comment: [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) is a getter inherited from `Object.prototype`. Also it's displayed specially in the console as the prototype chain link.